# MongoDb C# driver 2.4 - LINQ with dynamic GroupBy not supported

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

```
var result = await Events.AsQueryable()
            .Where(_ => _.Date >= from.Date && _.Date <= to.Date)
            .GroupBy(_ => _.SomeProp)
            .Select(n => new { n.Key, Count = n.Count() })
            .ToListAsync();
```

works like charm. But lets say that I want to aggregate by custom field - received in aggregateBy string parameter.
So I try:

```
var propertyToGroupBy = typeof(DiagnosticEvent).GetProperties()
                        .First(x => x.Name.ToLowerInvariant() == aggregateBy);
```

And then:

```
var result = await Events.AsQueryable()
            .Where(_ => _.Date >= from.Date && _.Date <= to.Date)
            .GroupBy(p => propertyToGroupBy.GetValue(p))
            .Select(n => new { n.Key, Count = n.Count() })
            .ToListAsync();
```

Which ends up in:

> GetValue of type System.Reflection.PropertyInfo is not supported in
>   the expression tree System.String Type.GetValue({document})

Any idea how to do it while sticking to LINQ?
I know that i can use Fluent API with:

```
var group = new BsonDocument { { "_id", $"${aggregateBy}"}, { "Count", new BsonDocument("$sum", 1) } };
```

But I want to be consistent with LINQ approach.

Full stack trace: https://pastebin.com/RNzXi1kj

Comment: @mjwills - it's not a duplicate - completly different topic. I know how to group by with LINQ and mongo - just looking for dynamic property solution.

Comment: Does using `AsEnumerable` between the `Where` and the `GroupBy` help?

Comment: @mjwills - it works but it materializes the query after where statement - so all objects are pulled from database and grouping phase take place on in-memory dataset. AsQueryable here is not AsQueryable from LINQ - it's from MongoDb.Driver.Linq and it returns IMognoQueryable - which is special case of AsQueryable - you could build full LINQ chain and all data is pulled in one read from db.

Comment: @lukpep Hey mate any chance you found a way to do that? (dynamic property grouping solution?)